# image and multiple line of text and links vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, vertical-alignment

I have an image and some text in p tag and link to be aligned vertically. it works nicely when I float the image. but when I use padding left in the p tag and the link, it doesn't get the padding perfectly.

[click here to see the image I need look like](http://prnt.sc/cpusej)

[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/salim56668/f9nL6psv/)

```css
.wrapper {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  clear:both
}

img {
  float: left;
}
p.text {
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  color: #222222;
}

a.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #777777;
}

a.date {
  color: #e10622;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
  <p class="text">Posted By: Simon  | <a href="#" class="date"> 26 July 2016</a></p>
  <a href="#" class="link">Days are all happiness is key
and Free</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
  <p class="text">Posted By: Simon  | <a href="#" class="date"> 26 July 2016</a></p>
  <a href="#" class="link">Days are all happiness is key
and Free</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
  <p class="text">Posted By: Simon  | <a href="#" class="date"> 26 July 2016</a></p>
  <a href="#" class="link">Days are all happiness is key
and Free</a>
</div>


<br>
<br>
<br>

<a href="http://prntscr.com/cpusej" style="text-align:center; display: block; padding: 10px; background: #f44; font-size: 18px">Please see here what I need</a>
```

thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `display: block;` to your `a.link` class styles.  Also, set `margin-right: 30px;` on your image, and remove the `padding-left: 30px;` styles from your `p.text` and `a.link` elements. Final CSS would be as follows:

```
.wrapper {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
p.text {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    color: #222222;
}

a.link {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #777777;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It solved my problem :) . But I would love to know why I must have to provide the margin in the img. what's the problem with the text?

Comment: Two reasons.  First, you only need to set/update it in one place instead of two. Second, because of the float on the image, any padding or margin on the elements next to it (i.e. the `p.text` and `a.link` elements) ignores the image entirely. Since your image is `100px`wide, your elements run into the image before hitting the padding/margin boundaries.  You could set your `margin-left` or `padding-left` to `130px` and it would technically work, but it seemed cleaner to me to just put it on the image.

Comment: Thank you very much. And sorry for bothering you. As I am a new learner, it will help me surely.
Have a good day :)

Comment: No problem. Please mark it as the correct answer so that others  in the same situation can find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick solution for you. Looks like you needed to add a container around the text and then add the padding you wish. See below for quick instructions.

Add the following to your css:

```
div.textcontainer{
padding-left:130px
}
```

Also remove padding-left:30px from p.text as shown below:

```
p.text {
display: block;
padding-bottom: 22px;
color: #222222;
}
```

and lastly add a container around the text as below:

```
<div class="textcontainer">
//Insert coding you wish
</div>
```

This is the quick fix to your solution. Ideally you would want to use something like bootstrap or some other css frame work to make this fluid in design. I hope this works for you.

Comment: It works fine, but not perfect for me. because I have to use this in several places. and the image size are not same everywhere. so I can't use this. thanks for the answer. :)